# Makefile Subdirectories

Tags: c, makefile, subdirectory

I'm attempting to organize my project directory as follows

shell
|inc/[header files]
|obj/[object files]
|src/[source files]
|Makefile
|Executable

Everything compiles without error with everything in the root folder, but I'm running into difficulty modifying my makefile to accommodate having everything in different directories.

Here's how my makefile looked without directories

```
OBJS = shutil.o parser.o sshell.o
HEADER_FILES = shell.h parser.h
EXECUTABLE = sshell
CFLAGS = -Wall
CC = gcc
#Create main executable
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS)
#Create object files
%.o: %.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I.  -c -o $@ $<
$(OBJS) : $(HEADER_FILES)
```

I've tried adding the directories into the definitions (for the obj/ and inc/ directories)

```
OBJS = obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o obj/sshell.o
```

And modified every instance of %.o and %.c to obj/%.o and src/%.c

Everything should be okay as far as I can tell, but I get this error when I go to make from the root directory

```
gcc -Wall -Iinc -c -o obj/shutil.o src/shutil.c
src/shutil.c:8:23: fatal error: inc/shell.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong here? I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: Have you tried adding to your compile flags: `-I..`? I personally would take the *.o building to makefile of src and building the final result in the lib file of build. I'm not saying this is the best, just how I do it. If you want to see a sample of my Makefiles, see [here](https://github.com/ShabbyX/shCompiler)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, and I'm using exactly the same command. Could you post the actual makefile you're using? Also, what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: looks like you changed shutil.c to #include "inc/shell.h". Change it back to "shell.h" and the -Iinc should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Change `-I.` to `-I${CURDIR}`. The former adds the directory of the source being compiled to the include path list, which would be `shell/src`. The latter adds `shell`, this is probably what you want.

You may also take a look at [Building multiple executables with similar rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123431/building-multiple-executables-with-similar-rules/7321954#7321954) for a micro non-recursive make framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is looking for inc/shell.h, which it shouldn't. Generally, no build system dependent path should be in the source file, but the details of the build system should rather be defined via compiler flags.

That is, your source file src/shutil.c should look like:

```
#include "shell.h"
```

and your compiler invocation be the same, with the -Iinc passing the include path.

By keeping the paths out of the source files, implementation and installation of header files is much simpler.

Comment: That's not exactly the best practise. It doesn't scale well (imagine a project with several shell.h header files). It is better to have header files directories copy namespace (prefix in C) structure, like "namespace_a/shell.h", "namespace_b/shell.h".

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I agree, even though none of the header directories should be called "inc" in this case. I assumed he'd have the logical subdirectories in inc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it took some thorough frustration, but I got it now.
I changed my definitions at the top to include the file paths, as so:

```
OBJS = obj/shutil.o obj/parser.o obj/sshell.o
HEADER_FILES = inc/shell.h inc/parser.h
```

And it seems the key was -I./inc, instead of -Iinc as I expected.

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I./inc -c -o $@ $<
```