# How to target multiple directories with a single Makefile?

Tags: makefile, less

I'm using GNU Make to build three different editions of a static html document.

I use Less as a CSS preprocessor.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
Makefile
160x600/style.less
300x250/style.less
728x90/style.less
```

This is my Makefile:

```
LESSC=lessc -x # use -x for debugging

.PHONY: all clean

all: 160x600 300x250 728x90

%.css: %.less
    $(LESSC) $< > $@

160x600: 160x600/style.css
300x250: 300x250/style.css
728x90: 728x90/style.css

clean:
    rm -f 160x600/*.css
    rm -f 300x250/*.css
    rm -f 728x90/*.css
```

This way, I can use `make 160x600` to build style.css from style.less.

But I don't want to explicitly list a target rule for each directory. Instead, I tried adding this rule instead of the three directory specific ones:

```
%: %/style.css
```

But that does not work. I assume it's clear from that example what my goal is. Is there a way to accept any directory as a target, so that I just have to list the directory names in the `all:` rule?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123431/building-multiple-executables-with-similar-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
res_dirs = 160x600 300x250 728x90

$(res_dirs): %: %/style.css
```

Comment: Thanks, the first approach worked perfectly :) The merged version not though.

Comment: @DaniloBargen, right, I see why. It is easier not to merge it, I deleted the second variant.