# Structuring Makefiles with multiple directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile my project which has the following structure

Project:

- MakeFile
- Executable
- Source1

  - *.cxx*
  - .h
- Source2

  - *.cxx*
  - .h
- Build

  - *.o

And I'm having difficulty writting a Makefile to compile.  I currently have commands like:

```
Src1 = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR1)/*.cxx)
Obj1 = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR1)/%.cxx, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(Src1))
```

But then I have difficulty making the compile rules for the object files a) Because I can no longer do:

```
$(Obj1): %.cxx
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $(@:.o=.cxx) -o $@
```

Because the '$@' command now includes the path of the build directory and b) because the prerequisites now include the build path and I should have a source path.  I have read large bits of the make manual to try and find a solution but no luck.
Any help towards a solution appreciated!
Jack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Comment: Thanks Maxim, thats a great answer.  However, the main difficulty I am having is building all the object codes to the BUILD directory when they exist in the SRC directory. Jack

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10612028/311567

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400732/makefile-target-multiple-directories

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, after playing around a bit with "raw" Makefiles, I'd really recommend using some tool building the Makefiles for you, like [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) or [cmake](http://www.cmake.org).

You'll still have to specify all the source files manually - but at least I prefer that to manually fiddling around with the Makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

One option I prefer is building an isomorphic directory structure in the build directory. That is, a source file `${src_dir}/project_x/main.cxx` builds into `${build_dir}/project_x/main.o`. This way you are protected from name clashes when there are source files with the same name in different source directories. The compiler rule would look something like:

```
${obj_dir}/%.o : ${src_dir}/%.cxx # % includes directory name, e.g. project_x/main
    @-mkdir -p ${@D}
    ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $<
```

Notice how in the above it creates the target directory on the fly. This is a bit simplistic, in a real-world build system object files depend (using [order-only dependency](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)) on its directory, so that `make` automatically creates the destination directory if it does not exist instead of speculatively trying to create them for each target object file even if it already exists.

Comment: FYI, you should normally never have a target depend on a directory.  If you really want to do this use make the directory an order-only prerequisite not a normal prerequisite (note this is a GNU make-only feature).

Comment: @MadScientist Adding/removing a file in a directory updates directory's timestamp, whereas we only care if it exists. So, as you correctly noted, order-only dependencies should be used for directories.

Comment: Ok this is definitely helping, most of my files arenow happy to make with the command ${obj_dir}/%.o : ${src_dir}/%.cxx.
The problem now is that I also have files which want to end up as ${obj_dir}/%.o files but arent in src_dir, they are in a seperate src directory.  Moreover I have a few fortran files which also need compiling and the ${obj_dir}/%.o : ${src_dir}/%.cxx rule does not cover them?

Comment: @JackMedley If you have source files in directories outside `${src_dir}` you can either symlink those dirs under `${src_dir}` or add another rule `${obj_dir}/%.o : ${another_src_dir}/%.cxx`