# Makefile for building multiple applications linking a previous built library

Tags: c, makefile

I think to organize my project as follows:

my_project

|--src

|--include

|--test

The core files reside in the directories src and include, whereas the different test applications of the core are within test directory (multiple *.c containing each a main() function). The core should be build as static library which will be linked to all applications).

How to write a basic Makefile to match these requirements? I already googled and found the following website providing a Makefile template for building an executable [1](http://felixcrux.com/blog/creating-basic-makefile) . How can this Makefile be extended for my needs?

If you think my project organization is bad or you have a better idea, let me know!

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks, Jonas

Comment: 1) Static or dynamic library? 2) Do you know how to do it "by hand", without Make? 3)The link is dead; don't use links in your questions if you can avoid them.

Comment: @Beta I've fixed the link

Comment: I also fixed the links. Thanks for the hint. Yes, I know how to create (shared/static) libraries on the bash using ar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123431/building-multiple-executables-with-similar-rules/7321954#7321954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said where you want the library to go, so I'll assume it should go into `src/` where the objects already go.

```
src/libcore.a: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) -cvq $@ $^
```

It looks as if the makefile you have will build `test/testfoo.o` from `test/testfoo.c` so I'll assume that that works. And you haven't said where you want the executable tests (e.g. `testfoo`) to go, so I'll put them in `test/`.

```
test/%: test/%.o src/libcore.a
    $(CC) -o $@ $< -Lsrc -lcore
```

**EDIT:**

If you want Make to build all of the tests by default, then you should have this before any other rule in the makefile:

```
TESTS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard test/*.c))

all: $(TESTS)
```

Comment: Hmm, I will have multiple c files each containing a main() function in the test directory, e.g. test1.c, test2.c, test3.c. The result should be the executables test1, test2 and test3. So, I am not sure if your test target works?

Comment: @Jonas: It works; for example, you can `make test1`. Do you mean that you want the default action to be the building of *all* tests?

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, make test1 does not work: make: *** No rule to make target `test1'.  Stop.

Comment: As I said, **I put the tests in `test/`.** So try `make test/test1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a few problems. I posted it as my answer in this thread. Maybe you can have a look at it? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small project called dotmk which turns the creation of a Makefile very easy.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/swrh/dotmk

You just have to run the install script and create the Makefile like the examples

Comment: Looks nice but I want don't want rely on third party scripts generating the makefile. Nevertheless, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: They don't generate Makefiles, they are pure Makefiles.
The only difference is that the resolution of dependencies are automatic.

Answer (score 0):

my Makefile now looks as follows:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc
AR    = ar

CFLAGS       = -std=gnu99 -Iinclude -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -ggdb3
DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG -combine -fwhole-program
PROFILEFLAGS = -pg

ARFLAGS      = -cvq

# core and test common includes
COMMON_INC          = include/definitions.h include/debug.h

# core stuff 
CORE_LIB            = lib/libcore.a
CORE_SRC            = $(shell echo src/*.c)
CORE_INC            = $(shell echo include/*.h)
CORE_OBJ            = $(CORE_SRC:.c=.o)
CORE_PUB_INC        =

# test stuff
TEST_SERVER         = test/server/server
TEST_SERVER_SRC     = $(shell echo test/server/*.c)
TEST_SERVER_INC     = $(shell echo test/server/*.h)
TEST_SERVER_OBJ     = $(TEST_SERVER_SRC:.c=.o)

TEST_CLIENT         = test/client/client
TEST_CLIENT_SRC     = $(shell echo test/client/*.c)
TEST_CLIENT_INC     = $(shell echo test/client/*.h)
TEST_CLIENT_OBJ     = $(TEST_CLIENT_SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(CORE_LIB) $(TEST_SERVER) $(TEST_CLIENT)

core: $(CORE_LIB)

server: core $(TEST_SERVER)

client: core $(TEST_CLIENT)

$(CORE_LIB): $(CORE_OBJ)
    $(AR) -cvq $@ $^

$(TEST_SERVER): $(TEST_SERVER_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Llib -lcore

$(TEST_CLIENT): $(TEST_CLIENT_OBJ)
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Llib -lcore


debug: CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug: all

profile: CFLAGS += $(PROFILEFLAGS)
profile: all

release: CFLAGS += $(RELEASEFLAGS)
release: all

.PHONY : clean depend

clean:
    -rm -f $(CORE_LIB) $(CORE_OBJ)
    -rm -f $(TEST_SERVER) $(TEST_SERVER_OBJ)
    -rm -f $(TEST_CLIENT) $(TEST_CLIENT_OBJ)
    -rm -f gmon.out

depend:
    @makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(CORE_SRC) $(TEST_SERVER_SRC) $(TEST_CLIENT_SRC)
```

I still have some problems:
- make creates the lib, the server and client test app. If I know modify one of the source files of the core (lib), make builds the lib newly, but not the server and client apps. Do I have a dependency problem?
- make or make all should build by default as DEBUG, whereas release and profile build a release, or profile version respectively.

I wonder, what is wrong in my makefile.

Thanks again!

Comment: 1) This should be a new question, not a new answer. 2) Yes, you have a dependency problem, in that `$(TEST_SERVER)` does not depend on `$(CORE_LIB)`-- I suggest `$(TEST_SERVER): $(TEST_SERVER_OBJ) $(CORE_LIB)`. 3) You're handling test sources in a dangerous way; I suggest a single source for each test, spelled out in the makefile: `TEST_SERVER_SRC = test/server/test_server.c`.

Comment: But the dependency problem still exists. If make the whole project and afterwards modify a core source file and now make the project again, only the core lib will be built. But the apps still have the old lib linked...