# Compiling and linking subfolders using different Makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I have a client/server application in C. The server has its own folder `dserver`, the same for the client `dclient`. Using both of them some files containing utility functions, I created another directory at the same level of the previously ones, named `common`.

My idea is to create each `Makefile` in each subfolder (one in `dserver`, one in `dclient` and another in `common`) and then one `Makefile` in the main directory which will run the other `Makefiles` which looks like:

```
all:
    +$(MAKE) -C common
    +$(MAKE) -C dserver
    +$(MAKE) -C dclient
```

The first problem is that the `common/Makefile` should not create an executable but only create the object files that will be needed to create the executable for the client and for the server. In my case it is:

```
CXX = gcc

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR=$(SOURCEDIR)/obj

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

My problem is that it is creating the object directory specified by `OBJDIR` but not the object files `*.o`: how should it be?

Secondly in the client and server `Makefile`s I should both include path to the files in `common` and then referencing the object files in the resulting from the compilation of `common` to build the executables. So taking for example the `dserver/Makefile` I added the line `INC_PATH = -I../common/` and referencing it in the compilation as `$(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@`. However in the code I had to do `#include "../common/utilities.h"`.

Is there a way to include the path in the Makefile so that in the code it allows to do just: `#include "utilities.h"`?

And also, supposing that `common` has its own object directory containing the object files needed both by the client and server, how build, for example the server executable referencing the object files both in the `common` directory and the ones specific and contained in the `server` directory?

The `dserver/Makefile` is something like (and the `dclient/Makefile` has the same structure):

```
CXX = gcc

INC_PATH = -I../common/

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR=./obj

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: server

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) server

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
../server: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@
    #$(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@
```

Comment: An example non-recursive make for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify any rules for building the objects in your "common" Makefile - this is the only rule you have.

```
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

You want to put a rule before that to all get it to build the objects, maybe something along the lines of:

```
all: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJECTS)
```

It has to go before the original rule as if you don't specify what is being built, make will do the first rule it finds.

Including header files from "common" in your other directories should be working just fine by using `-I../common/`.

Using the objects from "common" should just be a case of adding them to the list of objects ie:

```
COMMON_OBJECTS=../common/obj/utilities.o

../server: $(OBJECTS) $(COMMON_OBJECTS)
```

Or having them built into a library so you don't need to know what object files there are.

Also it's worth noting that `$(CXX)` is the variable used to store the C++ compiler - for building with the C compiler you want to be using `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)`.

Comment: `all: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJECTS)` breaks in parallel builds. The robust way is to have object files depend order-only on their directories. e.g. `%.o : %.cc | $$(@D)` (requires `.SECONDEXPANSION`).

Comment: `../server: $(OBJECTS) $(COMMON_OBJECTS)` is not working: it seems it is not linking properly: the error is `undefined reference to FunctionInCommonFile`

Comment: You are right about the rule in `common/Makefile` though

Comment: @FrancescoBoi that implies you've missed out one (or more) of the object files from common, or there is some code you've not yet written