# Single Makefile for sources in multiple sub directories

Tags: c++, makefile, subdirectory

In my C++ project the sources are organized inside a src directory. Inside the src directory are sub directories which all contain headers and source files, e.g.

```
project
├── Makefile
│
├── MyBinary
│
├── src
│    │
│    ├── main.cpp
│    │
│    ├── Application
│    │      │
│    │      ├── Application.h
│    │      └── Application.cpp
│    │      
│    │
│    └── Tasks
│           ├── BackgroundWorker.h
│           └── BackgroundWorker.cpp
│
└── obj
     ├── Application.o
     └── BackgroungWorker.o
```

I'm trying to create a Makefile so that all object files are created inside *obj* directory and the executable *MyBinary* is created above the *src* directory at the same level as the Makefile is.

It hasn't to be too complicated or automated. I don't mind manually specifying each .cpp and .h file in the Makefile.

But I'm new to Makefiles and unfortunately I'm struggling with this attempt:

```
CXX=c++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Os -g0

# Name of the output binary
APPNAME=MyBinary

# Source root directory
SRC_ROOT=src

# Object file directory
OBJ_DIR=obj

DEPS=$(SRC_ROOT)/Application/Application.h \
     $(SRC_ROOT)/Tasks/BackgroundWorker.h

_OBJ=$(SRC_ROOT)/Application/Application.o \
    $(SRC_ROOT)/Tasks/BackgroundWorker.o\
    $(SRC_ROOT)/main.o

OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

# This rule says that the .o file depends upon the .c version of the 
# file and the .h files included in the DEPS macro.
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
  $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

# Build the application.
# NOTE: The $@ represents the left side of the colon, here $(APPNAME)
#       The $^ represents the right side of the colon, here $(OBJ)
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
  $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
  rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(APPNAME)
```

The error when calling make is: **Fatal error: can't create obj/src/Application.o: File or directory not found.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: A working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))` prepends `obj/` to the words of `_OBJ`.  You want to replace the `src` by `obj` something which you can do with

```
OBJ=$(patsubst $(SRC_ROOT)/%,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
```

Note that the directory structure you get expect subdirectories `Application` and `Tasks` to `obj` you either have to create them manually before calling `make` or updating the Makefile to create them.

Here is something which behaves as I expect when the directory structure is pre-created.

```
APPNAME=MyBinary
SRC_ROOT=src
OBJ_DIR=obj

DEPS=$(SRC_ROOT)/Application/Application.h \
     $(SRC_ROOT)/Tasks/BackgroundWorker.h

_OBJ=$(SRC_ROOT)/Application/Application.o \
    $(SRC_ROOT)/Tasks/BackgroundWorker.o\
    $(SRC_ROOT)/main.o

OBJ=$(patsubst $(SRC_ROOT)/%,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_ROOT)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    echo Making $@ from $<
    touch $@ 

$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
    echo Making $@ from $^
    touch $@
```

Note that in practice you have to be finer with the dependencies and probably have them to be generated by the compiler (see `-MM` and similar options for g++), here you recompile everything when you change an header.

Comment: You also need to add a `mkdir -p $(@D)` to your compile recipes before invoking the compiler.  Compilers won't create directories for you, you have to be sure they exist before you ask the compiler to create files in them.

Comment: @AProgrammer Thank you - Unfortunately it still get an error. make: *** No rule to make target „obj/Application/Application.o“, needed by „MyBinary“.  Stop

Comment: `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)` should probably be `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_ROOT)/%.cpp $(DEPS)`.

Comment: @AProgrammer - Still the same error message. Maybe for this line it somehow has to be taken in account that some files (main.cpp) are directly in src/ while others (Application.cpp, ...) are in subdirectories of src/  ?

Comment: Thank you, @AProgrammer for your extended example. It is very descriptive and it works when replacing the touch'es with compiler calls.

Comment: @MadScientist - thanks for this hint, I'll take this into account.