# Reducing two similar make rules to one general rule

Tags: c++, makefile

Let's say I have two rules for making object files (each in `obj/`), one that depends on the `.cpp` files in directory A - let's call it `src` - and one that depends on the `.cpp` files directory B, which is a subdirectory of A - call it `src/demos`.  Their rules look like this:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/%.o : $(DEMODIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

As you can see, I am repeating a recipe in making two rules for these directories.  Is there a way I can "compress" these two rules into one?  I thought about using a wildcard in some way to match to both `src/*.cpp` and `src/demos/*.cpp`, but I am not sure how that would be implemented in a rule.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefiles with source files in different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories)

Comment: The accepted answer there is not the best.  Definitely the `VPATH` method is better.

Comment: Actually, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790486/4424636) to [Single Makefile for sources in multiple sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54790033/4424636) might be an option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this.

1. The simple one that places object files in a different directory and is robust against name clashes.
2. The one that preserves your exact directory structure but is a bit more complicated and not robust against name clashes.

---

Preamble variables used in both solutions (they will partly look differently in your real setting)

```
SRC=src/
DEMODIR=src/demos/
ODIR=out/
DEPS=

sources=$(wildcard $(SRC)*.cpp) $(wildcard $(DEMODIR)*.cpp)
```

---

### Solution 1 (my recommendation).

Object files follow the directory structure of source files.

```
objects=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(ODIR)%.o,$(sources))
$(objects): $(ODIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

### Solution 2 (your directory structure).

```
objects=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(ODIR)%.o,$(sources))
flatobjects=$(patsubst $(ODIR)$(SRC)%, $(ODIR)%, $(objects))
f_retrieve=$$(findstring $(join $(SRC),$(1:.o=.cpp)),$(sources)) $$(findstring $(join $(DEMODIR),$(1:.o=.cpp)),$(sources))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(flatobjects): $(ODIR)%.o: $(call f_retrieve,%.o) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

This will likely break the second you have both `src/a.cpp` and `src/demos/a.cpp`, so Solution 1 is recommended on that basis alone.

The trick is to search for each target's prequisite in the `$(sources)` variable for a matching source file (via `findstring`). Note the `.SECONDEXPANSION` section and the double `$` before `findstring`. Doing this directly should work in theory, but GNU make doesn't like it inside the rule. Relaxing the expression to be expanded twice then works.

#### Demo (solution 2)

```
./src: a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
./src/demos: x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp
```

Additional helper rule: `flatobjects: $(flatobjects)`

```
$ make flatobjects 
gcc -c -o out/a.o src/a.cpp 
gcc -c -o out/b.o src/b.cpp 
gcc -c -o out/c.o src/c.cpp 
gcc -c -o out/x.o src/demos/x.cpp 
gcc -c -o out/y.o src/demos/y.cpp 
gcc -c -o out/z.o src/demos/z.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up going with your first suggestion.  I had thought earlier to make my `obj` folder mirror my `src` folder, but didn't follow through with the idea because I figured I wasn't thinking about it correctly.