# Using a make file to compile files in separate directories

Tags: c, makefile

OK, I have never been able to grasp make, and makefiles. I've tried reading through the manpages with no luck. So I have come here :L

I have a bunch of files that are starting to get very un-managed in one file. ( I'm trying to make an OS ) And I want to try and split these files into separate sub-directories ( see structure below ) and then tell make to 'make' the files into an their .o files, moving them into another separate sub-directory and finally ending up with a kernel file. ( Sorry if that sounds complicated, hopefully the structure will help make things clearer )

So this is my intended structure tree:

```
                                  Parent directory 
                           ( where the makefile will be )
                                          |
                                          |
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                 |                  |                |                 |
  Header SubDir      Source SubDir      ASM SubDir      Obj SubDir        Kern SubDir
(Header files )     (Source Files)     (Assembly Files)  (Object Files)   (Kernel File)
```

This is my current makefile:

```
C_SOURCES= main.c
S_SOURCES= boot.s
C_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c, obj/%.o, $(C_SOURCES))
S_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.s, obj/%.o, $(S_SOURCES))
CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld -melf_i386 --oformat=elf32-i386
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: kern/kernel

.PHONY: clean
clean:
-rm -f kern/kernel

kern/kernel: $(S_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS)
ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(C_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : %.c 
gcc $(CFLAGS) $<

vpath %.c source

$(S_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : %.s
nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<

vpath %.s asem
```

It's now spitting out this error:

```
ld -Tlink.ld -melf_i386 --oformat=elf32-i386 -o kern/kernel obj/boot.o obj/main.o
ld: cannot find obj/boot.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find obj/main.o: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Jamie.

Comment: Related: [GNU `make` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories

Comment: Pavan Manjunath No this isn't a duplicate, it's slightly related to that post, but I'm doing it completely differently.

 bitmask How do I write the makefile to compile and link the source files that are in different subdirectories?

Comment: You never set `OBJECTS` -- you probably want `OBJECTS=$(C_OBJECTS) $(S_OBJECTS)`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks, any idea's in why it's still spitting out the new error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this in stages:

```
all: $(SOURCES) link
```

You don't have to build the sources, so let's leave that out. And what you really want to build is `kern/kernel`, so let's use that instead of the abstract "link:

```
all: kern/kernel

kern/kernel:
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)
```

But you want to link the *object files*, not the source files, and produce `kernel` in `kern/`, not in the parent directory (where I assume you will be running `make`):

```
kern/kernel: $(OBJECTS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

And what are the objects? Well, I presume the sources are the `.s` files, and the objects have the same names with a different suffix, and in a different location:

```
SOURCES=boot.s main.s monitor.s common.s descriptor_tables.s isr.s interrupt.s gdt.s timer.s kheap.s paging.s

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.s,Obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

And this is how you make an object:

```
$(OBJECTS): Obj/%.o : %.s
    nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<

vpath %.s Src
```

(That last line is so that Make will know where to find the sources.)

The flags look good. And here's clean:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f Obj/*.o kern/kernel
```

You're trying to do a lot at once, so this probably won't work on the first try. Give it a whirl and let us know the result.

Comment: The sources are a mix of .s and .c so I will guess I change the SOURCES= boot.s... etc to the relevent suffix?

Comment: @JamieEdwards, It would have been good to mention that in your question. The easiest way is to have `C_SOURCES` and `S_SOURCES`, and also `C_OBJECTS` and `S_OBJECTS`, and a rule for compiling `c` files.

Comment: My sincerest apologise. I should have put the suffix's of the files in :L noobish thing to do really.

Comment: Just updated OP with my new makefile, and it's spitting out error's which I have also edited in. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `$(S_OBJECTS)` instead of `$(OBJECTS)`.

Comment: @JamieEdwards, use `kern/kernel: $(S_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS)`.

Comment: I did as you said, and it spits out another error, although I think we're almost there! But I have updated the OP with new errors, Do I now have to make another $() for the headers too?

Comment: @JamieEdwards, try `gcc $(CFLAGS) -IHeader $<`.

Comment: According to make, the make file isn't putting the object files into the 'obj' directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamieEdwards, your `$(C_OBJECTS)` command is wrong. It should be `gcc $(CFLAGS) -IHeader $< -o $@` (sorry I didn't notice that when I was thinking about the header problem). Now about finding the header files; confirm that `Header/monitor.h` is there, then try `gcc -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -IHeader src/main.c -o Obj/main.o` from the command line, and see what happens.

Comment: @JamieEdwards, in my previous comment, each gcc command should have a `-c` flag as well, but I'm having trouble editing the comment.

Comment: @Beta I actually figured out that problem and it's now finding the header files. Only problem now is that the makefile isn't transferring the resulting object files into the obj directory, which is preventing ld from linking the files into one kernel file. I've updated OP for you to see what is wrong.

Comment: @Beta - Scratch what I just wrote above! I finally have my makefile doing what I want with yourself and everyone else's help! Thank you so much for your patience, and help!