# How to link files in different folders produced by calling multiple make files?

Tags: c, linker, makefile

I have the following make file

```
all:    XmlNode.o y.tab.o   y.tab.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -o prog y.tab.o lex.yy.o XmlAttributeNode.o XmlNode.o -ll -ly -lm

XmlNode.o:  
    cd XmlNode; make
y.tab.o: y.tab.c
    gcc -g -c y.tab.c
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
y.tab.c: LexYacc/prog1.y
    bison -y -dv LexYacc/prog1.y
lex.yy.c: LexYacc/prog1.l
    lex -l LexYacc/prog1.l

clean:
    rm -f y.tab.* lex.yy.* *.o prog
```

`XmlAttributeNode.o` and `XmlNode.o` are made in the `XmlNode` folder, thus I get the error

```
gcc: XmlAttributeNode.o: No such file or directory
gcc: XmlNode.o: No such file or directory
```

I looked at the following questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044433/using-a-make-file-to-compile-files-in-separate-directories), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341387/adding-a-directory-for-the-headers-in-a-makefile), but I can't seem to find how I can get a list of all the .o files produced by XmlNode.o so 1) I don't have to type them by hand and 2) the proper path is included so gcc can find the .o files. So something like this:

```
 XmlNode.o: 
    cd XmlNode; XmlNodeList = .o files from this make; XmlPath = `pwd`;
```

and then:

```
 all:   XmlNode.o y.tab.o   y.tab.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -o prog y.tab.o lex.yy.o XmlPath/XmlNodeList -ll -ly -lm
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)?

Comment: It seems useful information thanks.

Comment: So... in the `XmlNode.o` rule you want to run Make in `XmlPath/`, using `XmlPath/Makefile`, which will produce several .o files in `XmlPath/`, and then you want to use a list of those files in the main makefile?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the info in the comments, this will at least work.

```
all:    XmlNode.o y.tab.o   y.tab.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -o prog y.tab.o lex.yy.o XmlNode/XmlAttributeNode.o XmlNode/XmlNode.o -ll -ly -lm

XmlNode/XmlAttributeNode.o XmlNode/XmlNode.o:  
    cd XmlNode; make
y.tab.o: y.tab.c
    gcc -g -c y.tab.c
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
y.tab.c: LexYacc/prog1.y
    bison -y -dv LexYacc/prog1.y
lex.yy.c: LexYacc/prog1.l
    lex -l LexYacc/prog1.l

clean:
    rm -f y.tab.* lex.yy.* *.o prog; cd XmlNode; make clean
```