# How to use variables properly in Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, sfml

I was following a tutorial for creating a simple pong game and wanted to try using makefiles. I did some research and wrote one, but i can't get it to work.
This is how my project folder looks like.

```
project/
|__include/
|  |__*.h
|__release/
|  |__obj/
|  |__Makefile
|__src/
   |__*.cpp
```

This is my Makefile:

```
CXX         :=  g++

# Directories
SDIR        :=  ../src
IDIR        :=  ../include
ODIR        :=  ./obj
VPATH       :=  $(SDIR)

# Files
_SRCS       :=  stdafx.cpp Pang.cpp Game.cpp MainMenu.cpp SplashScreen.cpp
SRCS        :=  $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_SRCS))
_DEPS       :=  stdafx.h Game.h MainMenu.h SplashScreen.h
DEPS        :=  $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
_OBJS       :=  $(_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS        :=  $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJS))
EXES        :=  Pang

# Parameters
CXXFLAGS    :=  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
LIBS        :=  -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

# Default rule
all: $(SRCS) $(EXES)

# Generic compilation rule
$(ODIR)%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Link object files
$(EXES): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

# Clean Rule
clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o $(EXES)
```

When i run make, this is what i get:

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/stdafx.o', needed by `Pang'.  Stop.
```

The SFML seemed to be working before, so i don't think it is the problem. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: I suggest you to use `remake -x` to debug your makefile issues. You could also use a better builder, such as http://omake.metaprl.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yet another build system? And this one requires whole OCaml, great idea!

Comment: Many distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, ...) already are packaging `omake`

Comment: Do you have `stdafx.cpp` file?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I used <code>remake -x</code>, but I got nothing useful for this case.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Yes, it's inside include.

Comment: @engrato: `include`? It should be inside `src` with these rules (note `.cpp` not `.h`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, we have it too. And it requires OCaml and gamin. I'll remember to stay away from it.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Sorry. I meant
    src.

Comment: Hrm. Where did you get such an insane Makefile?

Comment: You could even run `remake x -d`  which shows a lot of debugging output. This should be enough to debug your makefile. You might want `vpath` (but I am not sure).

Comment: Mostly from the last example from [here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).
A little bit from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories).

Comment: Looks like your generic .cpp -> .o rule is wrong. It shouldn't mention the output directory, this is already done with the substitutions, and even worse there's no path separator. Just try `%.o : %.cpp`.

Comment: @g-makulik: The path separator really was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this:

```
$(ODIR)%.o : %.cpp
```

should be:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : %.cpp
```

(note the slash)

The first one is a rule which expects files like `./objstdafx.o` to be created. The second one expects files like `./obj/stdafx.o`. So with the first one, make does not know how to build `obj/stdafx.o`.

See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match) for more information about pattern matching rules.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I also had to add `-I$(IDIR)` to `CXXFLAGS`.