# How to merge two Makefiles (each builds scripts with certain environment variables set) into a single Makefile?

Tags: c++, merge, makefile

I have two different directories with two different C++ source codes each of them execute different program. Directories have their own Makefiles each of them builds scripts with certain environment variables set.

Now, I want to put both directories' contents into a single directory as I want to mix both C++ source codes in order to develop a new C++ source code that utilizes both programs capabilities.

So far, I placed all files in a single directory, and I can successfully build each of the original source codes when I place the corresponding Makefile. Now, I want to have a single Makefile that allows me to build each of the original source codes (without replacing the Makefile), and hopefully this would allow me to build the new mixed C++ source file...

I tried a trivial solution and I placed the contents of both Makefiles into a single Makefile and this didn't work ...

I think it is useful to post my two Makefiles

Here is the first one

```
# A simple $(MAKE)file to cause make to go look in the top directory. A simple
# convenience.

all: lib 
    $(MAKE) -C .. examples

lib:
    $(MAKE) -C .. lib/libAria.so

%.so: ../lib/libAria.so %.cpp 
    $(MAKE) -C .. examples/$@

%: ../lib/libAria.so %.cpp 
    $(MAKE) -C .. examples/$@

%Static: ../lib/libAria.a %.cpp 
    $(MAKE) -C .. examples/$@

clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C .. cleanExamples

../lib/libAria.so: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -C .. dirs lib/libAria.so

../lib/libAria.a: FORCE 
    $(MAKE) -C .. dirs lib/libAria.a

FORCE:

.PHONY: all FORCE clean lib
```

And the second Makefile is

```
LDLIBS = -lm 
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -finline-functions -I. -I./qpoases/INCLUDE -I./qpoases/SRC
CFLAGS = -O3
CC     = g++

OBJECTS = \
    ./qpoases/SRC/QProblemB.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Bounds.o          \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Constraints.o     \
    ./qpoases/SRC/SubjectTo.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Indexlist.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/CyclingManager.o  \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Utils.o           \
    ./qpoases/SRC/MessageHandling.o \
    ./qpoases/solver.o              \
    integrator.o                    \
    condensing.o                    \
    gauss_newton_method.o 

.PHONY: all
all: test libacado_exported_rti.a

test: ${OBJECTS} test.o

./qpoases/solver.o    : ./qpoases/solver.hpp
integrator.o          : acado.h
condensing.o          : acado.h
gauss_newton_method.o : acado.h   ./qpoases/solver.hpp
test.o                : acado.h   ./qpoases/solver.hpp

libacado_exported_rti.a: ${OBJECTS}
    ar r $@ $?

${OBJECTS} : ./qpoases/solver.hpp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.a ./qpoases/SRC/*.o ./qpoases/SRC/*.a test
```

I check all stackoverflow questions related to my question and the only closest situation to mine is a question titled (**multiple makefiles in one directory**);however, this is not exactly what I want to do...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Make one makefile that runs make on the other two? Unless you specifically NEED to have a single makefile, for some reason, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to merge your source directories?  I assume they are seperated for a reason.  Instead, I'd leave them be and create a new make file in the directory above them that calls each of the sub makes files below it - either via includes or via shelling directly to each makefile.  I would not mix the code just to make it "easier" to get inheritance or whatever working.

BTW, here's a link for you:[Stack Overflow shows you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories)

Comment: Well, this may allow me to build each of the original source codes, but will not allow me to build a mixed source code as I referred above. Mixing the codes into a single file is necessary for me as this compiled file will be transferred uploaded onto a robot platform.

Comment: Why not?  Your linker should take care of this for you yes?  #include's will catch your declares and your good.  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Let me put it this way ... My new mixed code will be finally something like a big while loop. Inside this loop I will need to use operations from the two original source codes and each of these operations will need its own (environment variables set) ... So, if I follow your recommendation, would I be able to do something like that?

Comment: Michael Dorgan ... I am explaining what I really want to do in this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814950/how-to-compile-a-two-mixed-c-source-codes-from-different-packages-in-a-single