# How to select *.c files with Makefile?

Tags: makefile

This is a kind of silly question, but this is first time I am using `Makefile`.
I am having trouble with selecting files. When I used this command,

```
target1:

     $(CC) -o target *.c
```

it worked well.
But this doesn't work,

```
SRCS = dir1/*.c
target1:

     $(CC) -o target $(SRCS)
```

and spits this error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dir1/*.c'
```

Obviously this because my variable `SRCS` is escaped before passed.
How can I make Makefile pass the string as is? Or is there another conventional/designed way to do this? (selecting file by pattern)

Comment: you might find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139271/makefiles-with-source-files-in-different-directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `wildcard` keyword to select all the files matching a certain pattern like this:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard dir1/*.c)
target1:

     $(CC) -o target $(SRCS)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SRCS := $(shell echo dir1/*.c)
target1:
    $(CC) -o target $(SRCS)
```